# immutable borrow occurs when get from HashSet

Tags: rust, lifetime

```rust
let mut set = HashSet::<u32>::new();

let a = set.get(&1);
set.remove(&1);
a.unwrap(); // cannot borrow `set` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
```

Here is my code. I see what the error means and why rust prevent me doing it.
But I can't find any type annotation in `set.rs` to make that error happen.

```rust
 pub fn get<Q: ?Sized>(&self, value: &Q) -> Option<&T>
        where T: Borrow<Q>,
              Q: Hash + Eq
```

This is the declaration of `set.get` but I can't see anything relevant.

Answer (score 0):

The important part of `get` is the following: `-> Option<&T>`.

Contrary to what you seem to be believing, this method gives you a **reference**, not the actual object (and doing so also establishes an immutable borrow on the item). As a result, when you then `remove()` said object (and get a mutable borrow over the collection), the reference is evidently immediately invalidated, and as a result, it is impossible for you to `unwrap()` it.

You may be looking to `take()` the set element instead of `get()`. This will return the object and remove the item from the set, instead of returning a reference; it also means that you will no longer need the call to `remove()` either ([**playground**](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=939455e660b053e90f31d9952c9a6977)):

```
let mut set = HashSet::<u32>::new();
set.insert(1);
let a = set.take(&1).unwrap();
```

Comment: The error message is telling `a` is borrowing `set`. But `Option<&T>` doesn't seem to borrow `set` itself.
The type signature of `take` differs just in `&mut self`.

Comment: @user3584499 Rust's ownership/borrowing system is not tuned to discern individual elements of a set; as such, when you acquire a reference to a member of a set, you also acquire indirectly the same type of reference to the set itself. When you think about it, it is pretty logical, as well; and it allows anybody needing more fine-tuned constraints to implement it themselves via interior mutability